# GLSL - Object disappears when multiplying by matrix

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I've got this vertex shader:

```
#version 400

layout(location=0) in vec4 vertPosition;
layout(location=1) in vec2 vertUV;
layout(location=2) in vec3 vertNormal;

uniform mat4 MVP;

out vec3 fragPosition;
out vec2 fragUV;
out vec3 fragNormal;

void main(void){
    gl_Position = MVP * vertPosition;

    fragPosition = (MVP * vertPosition).rgb;
    fragUV = vertUV;
    fragNormal = (MVP * vec4(vertNormal,0)).rgb;
}
```

As soon as I'm multiplying `vertPosition` by `MVP` the object to render disappears, even if `MVP` is an identity matrix.

Here's the code where I'm setting MVP:

```
mat4 model = translate(mat4(), vec3(0,0,0));
mat4 view = translate(mat4(), vec3(0,0,-10));
mat4 proj = perspective(90.0f, (float)1280/720, 0.001f, 1000.0f);

mat4 MVP = model * view * proj;

GLint uniform_loc = glGetUniformLocation(this->_shaderID, "MVP");
glUniformMatrix4fv(uniform_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, value_ptr(matrix));
```

I tried different multiplication orders and multiplicating in the shader.

Comment: Do you get anything from `GLGeterror()`?  I think you have to upcast your `vec3()` to `vec4()` before multiplying a `mat4` by them.  No nevermind, that code is in your prog not in your GLSL.  You do wrap them in `vec4()`

Comment: By the way, what do you need the clip-space position (`MVP * vertPosition`) for in your fragment shader? Technically it is not clip-space because you chopped off the important `W` component (which is used for clipping, hence the name), but it still does not seem particularly useful. Fragment shaders already implicitly include a position (`gl_FragCoord`) defined in screen space, depending on what you are using `fragPosition` for, you may not need  it at all.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the order in which you multiple MVP reversed. OpenGL matrix multiplication is column major right associative, hence it should be

```
mat4 MVP = proj * view * model;
```

A near clipping plane distance of `0.0001` is far too low. Essentially you're compressing all of the depth buffer resolution into a very small range. Make near as large as possible.

I don't get why you're selecting `.rgb` for the `fragPosition` and `fragNormal`.

Comment: @LiessJemai: Your near clipping plane distance is also problematic.

Comment: Okay, I'm fixing that. But the object disappears, even if I'm just multiplying by a identity.

Answer (score 0):

From the look of your example you have forgotten to set the shader program before setting the uniform. Try using `glUseProgram(this->program);` (depending on where you've stored your program) before setting the matrix!